# Font Awesome Unicode - How to float icon all the way to the right

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I know how to do this if the icon was using the traditional `<i></i>` tags, but instead I am using the fa icon as Unicode after the link.

So my link CSS looks like this:

```
#menu li a:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f054";
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The icon appears next to the link on the right which is correct, but how can I align the icon all the way to the right??

All the way to the end of the width of the menu.

I'm trying `float: right`, but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Can you post your `#menu` HTML content too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take away the **float** and **display** properties and use the **position** and **right** properties instead

```
#menu li a:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f054";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```